# Recompile/reload a file in Common Lisp and remove functions which are no longer in the file

Tags: common-lisp, development-environment

During development I often remove functions which are no longer needed from their respective files. These functions are still defined in the Lisp system.

How can I (without restarting my Common Lisp image) reload / recompile the code in such a way that only functions which are still present in my source files are defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you now that symbol `f` denotes a function  that you no longer want to exist, then you can call [`fmakunbound`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_fmakun.htm#fmakunbound):

```
(fmakunbound f)
```

Often, that also means that the symbol is no longer useful, so you can [`unintern`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_uninte.htm) it:

```
(unintern f)
```

Note that `unintern` implies `fmakunbound`, you only need to do one of these calls.

Now, if you no longer know which function was removed and you are working with Slime/Swank, then you can use its cross-referencing mechanism to detect which function is never called:

```
(defun iterate-uncalled-symbols (package function)
  (let ((package (find-package package)))
    (do-symbols (s package)
      (when (eq (symbol-package s) package)
        (when (fboundp s)
          (unless (swank/backend:who-calls (symbol-function s))
            (funcall function s)))))))
```

**warning**: you should first print the symbols or collect them into a list before deleting them, because this will also include functions that should be called by the user and are as such never called by any other function, etc.

Finally, you can always call [`delete-package`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_del_pk.htm) and reload the system (e.g. with ASDF or Quicklisp, possibly with a `:force t` argument if no file is modified).

```
(delete-package :my-package)
(asdf:make "my-system" :force t)
```

Note that in some environments `delete-package` may enter the debugger to ask for confirmation, if the package is being used by another one.

Answer (score 2):

This is fiddly to do in general.  It's fairly easy to work out which interned symbols get created by loading a file (or any other operation), and to have some notion of an 'interesting' symbol such as one that is bound or fbound.  But you very rapidly run into a huge morass of questions which don't have really general answers at all.

Here is one approach: there are certainly others.  This approach has the property that it's aware of packages, and in particular it restricts itself to a list of packages, which by default contains only the current package, but it doesn't muck around with the package system at all: it doesn't unintern symbols, or change their package, or delete packages, or anything like that.  This is entirely intentional: changing the state of the package system is something that's just fraught with excitement in a bad way.

The code below is *very much* a first draft.

Start by defining a notion of what makes a symbol interesting in a package and how to make it not be interesting.  For example a symbol might be interesing in a package if:

- the package is the package of the symbol;
- it is either bound or fbound.

Here is such a pair of definitions:

```
(defun interesting-symbol-p (s p)
  ;; is S interesting in P?  Interesting means:
  ;; - S's package is P (so CAR is not interesting in CL-USER)
  ;; - it's either bound or fbound
  (and (eq (symbol-package s) p)
       (or (boundp s)
           (fboundp s))))

(defun make-symbol-uninteresting (s p)
  ;; Make S be uninteresting in P
  (unless (eq (symbol-package s) p)
    (error "~S's home package is ~A not ~A" s 
           (package-name (symbol-package s))
           (package-name p)))
  (makunbound s)
  (fmakunbound s)
  s)
```

All the remaining code parameterizes for this pair of functions: you can provide your own.

Now define a macro which will evaluate some forms and return the new interesting symbols in one or more packages created by those forms.  This example (which does not pretend to be optimal) uses Tim Bradshaw's [`collecting`](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#collecting-lists-forwards-and-accumulating-collecting) macro:

```
(defun call/new-interesting-symbols (f &key
                                       (packages (list *package*))
                                       (interesting-symbol-p #'interesting-symbol-p)
                                       (external nil))
  ;; Return the (first) value of f and a list of new interesting
  ;; symbols in some packages.
  (let ((already-interesting
         (collecting
           (dolist (p packages)
             (if external
                 (do-external-symbols (s p)
                   (when (funcall interesting-symbol-p s p)
                     (collect s)))
               (do-symbols (s p)
                 (when (funcall interesting-symbol-p s p)
                   (collect s))))))))
    (values
     (funcall f)
     (collecting
       (dolist (p packages)
         (if external
             (do-external-symbols (s p)
               (when (and (funcall interesting-symbol-p s p)
                          (not (member s already-interesting)))
                 (collect s)))
           (do-symbols (s p)
             (when (and (funcall interesting-symbol-p s p)
                        (not (member s already-interesting)))
               (collect s)))))))))

(defmacro with-new-interesting-symbols ((&rest options &key &allow-other-keys)
                                       &body forms)
  `(call/new-interesting-symbols (lambda () ,@forms)
                                 ,@options))
```

Now the trick is to keep track of the interesting symbols created by loading a file, and then, before reloading that file, make all the symbols it made interesting last time be uninteresting, and record the current set of interesting symbols in case it created any new ones.  There is a special exemption here: if a symbol names a constant don't kill it.  Perhaps there should be others.

```
(defvar *file-interesting-symbols* (make-hash-table :test #'equal))

(defun load/cleaning (f &key
                        (load-options '())
                        (packages (list *package*))
                        (external nil)
                        (interesting-symbol-p #'interesting-symbol-p)
                        (make-symbol-uninteresting #'make-symbol-uninteresting))
  ;; Load F, making any of its interesting symbols in PACKAGES uninteresting first
  (let* ((tf (truename f))
        (already-interesting (gethash tf *file-interesting-symbols* '())))
    (dolist (s already-interesting)
      (unless (constantp s)
        (funcall make-symbol-uninteresting s (symbol-package s))))
    (multiple-value-bind (load-result newly-interesting)
        (with-new-interesting-symbols (:packages packages
                                      :external external
                                      :interesting-symbol-p interesting-symbol-p)
          (apply #'load f load-options))
      (values load-result
              (setf (gethash tf *file-interesting-symbols*)
                    (union already-interesting newly-interesting))))))
```

Finally here's a package cleaner: this just goes over one or more packages making all the interesting symbols not be.  This has the same constant exemption.

```
(defun clean-package (p &key
                        (external nil)
                        (interesting-symbol-p #'interesting-symbol-p)
                        (make-symbol-uninteresting #'make-symbol-uninteresting))
  (if external
      (do-external-symbols (s p p)
        (when (and (funcall interesting-symbol-p s p)
                   (not (constantp s)))
          (funcall make-symbol-uninteresting s p)))
    (do-symbols (s p p)
      (when (and (funcall interesting-symbol-p s p)
                 (not (constantp s)))
        (funcall make-symbol-uninteresting s p)))))
```

Comment: that's a nice way to do it

Comment: @coredump: I'm not sure there is a *nice* way...

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to remove the functionality while you are editing.

For example the LispWorks Editor of its IDE has the following commands to undefine functionality:

- undefine
- undefine buffer
- undefine region

This removes the defined functionality from the running Lisp. Then delete/comment the definitions in the source.

Other IDEs may have similar commands.